# dynamically get screen width and add to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code getting the screen width and then getting a percent of that to add to a div width. Is there a way to make this dynamic as in if the screen changes by user scaling down it will update? Note: I cant use CSS % because the site is a horizontal slider so CSS % grabs the width of the whole site, not the screen.

```
//Get screen width then make the slide left content box 30% of that
      var screeWidth = $(window).width();
      var leftWidth = screeWidth * .38;
      $('.slideLeft').css('width', leftWidth);
```

Comment: Why not just set the width of `.slideLeft` to `38%`, or `38vw` using CSS? That way it's automatically responsive without the need of any JS code.

Comment: Like I said in the post I cant. Using css like that with fullpage.js spans the width of the entire site not just the screen. The site is a really wide horizontal slider.

Comment: wait is the css VW just for the viewport? I didnt know about that one. I will try it.

Comment: VW worked. If you make that an answer I will accept it. Thanks. @RoryMcCrossan